# Expression Tree to List of String

Tags: haskell, expression-trees

This is my project, and the continuation of my previous question.

[Haskell creating new data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37100836/haskell-creating-new-data)

This is the essential parts of my code.

```
data Lukasiewicz = C | I | U
    deriving (Eq,  Show, Ord)
data LExpTree a = L a
                | V [Char]
                | N (LExpTree a)
                | Q (LExpTree a)
                | S (LExpTree a)
                | K (LExpTree a)
                | A ((LExpTree a), (LExpTree a))
                | O ((LExpTree a), (LExpTree a))
                | E ((LExpTree a), (LExpTree a))
                | M ((LExpTree a), (LExpTree a))
                deriving (Show, Eq)

type Dict = [(String, Lukasiewicz)] 

type Unary a b = a -> b
type Unary2 a = a -> a
type Binary b = b -> b -> b

fold :: LExpTree a -> Unary a b -> Unary [Char] b -> Unary2 b -> Unary2 b -> Unary2 b -> Unary2 b -> Binary b -> Binary b -> Binary b -> Binary b -> b
fold (L x) l v n q s k a o e m =  l x
fold (V x) l v n q s k a o e m =  v x
fold (N x) l v n q s k a o e m =  n (fold x l v n q s k a o e m)
fold (Q x) l v n q s k a o e m =  q (fold x l v n q s k a o e m)
fold (S x) l v n q s k a o e m =  s (fold x l v n q s k a o e m)
fold (K x) l v n q s k a o e m =  k (fold x l v n q s k a o e m)
fold (A x) l v n q s k a o e m =  a (fold (left' x) l v n q s k a o e m) (fold (right' x) l v n q s k a o e m)
fold (O x) l v n q s k a o e m =  o (fold (left' x) l v n q s k a o e m) (fold (right' x) l v n q s k a o e m)
fold (E x) l v n q s k a o e m =  e (fold (left' x) l v n q s k a o e m) (fold (right' x) l v n q s k a o e m)
fold (M x) l v n q s k a o e m =  m (fold (left' x) l v n q s k a o e m) (fold (right' x) l v n q s k a o e m)

evalT :: Dict -> LExpTree Lukasiewicz -> Lukasiewicz
evalT xs x = fold x id (lk xs) negation possible sure unknown (<&>) (<|>) (<->) (-->)
```

The last function `evalT` will take a `Dict` and `Expression Tree` and will spit out the result of that expression provided that the user will give the value for all variables for `V [Char]` in the expression tree in `Dict` list.

Now I need to create a new function which will evaluate the expression tree.
This time, the input won't have `Dict`. So, the output is not the result but the list of all variable names.

My idea is to use the same `fold` function and to ignore everything except `V [Char]`. The rest should just call the expression tree, and should not do anything else.

But I have no idea how to start.

The signature of the function should be

```
varList :: LExpTree Lukasiewicz -> [String]
```

Comment: The fact that `fold` takes *so* many arguments without actually using them (other than to pass them on to recursive calls) suggests that `fold` doesn't actually need so many arguments.

Comment: I am wondering the same thing. So for this new function, should I create a new `fold`? or sth? I couldn't think a way to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conventional way to write `varList` is like this:

```
varList (V x) = [x]
varList (L _) = []
varList (N e) = varList e  -- same for all unary nodes, e.g. Q, S, K, ...
varList (A a b) = varList a ++ varList b
  -- same for the other binary nodes
```

So compare:

```
fold (N x) l v n q s k a o e m =  n (fold x l v n q s k a o e m)
varList (N x)                  =  varList x
```

Convince yourself that:

```
varList blah == fold blah l v n ... e m
```

With this identification,

```
varList x == n (fold x l v n ... e m) == n (varList x)
```

and therefore `n` must be `id`, the identity function.

Another example... determining `l`:

```
varList (L x) == fold (L x) l ... e m
              == l (fold x  l ... e m)
              == l (varList x)
              == []
```

so `l (varList x) == []` which means that `l` must be ...?

Comment: Thanks. I came up with something that is basically what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
fold2 :: LExpTree a -> [String]
fold2  (L x) = []
fold2 (V x) = [x]
fold2 (N x) = fold2 (x)
fold2 (Q x) = fold2 (x)
fold2 (S x) = fold2 (x)
fold2 (K x) = fold2 (x)
fold2 (A x) = (fold2 (left' x)) ++ (fold2 (right' x))
fold2 (O x) = (fold2 (left' x)) ++ (fold2 (right' x))
fold2 (E x) = (fold2 (left' x)) ++ (fold2 (right' x))
fold2 (M x) = (fold2 (left' x)) ++ (fold2 (right' x))

varList :: LExpTree Lukasiewicz -> [String]
varList x = [y | y <- fold2 x]
```